# No entra en los if (que he marcado)

Tags: java, android, string

Tengo este código y aunque he comprobado todos los valores (que están todos bien) sigue sin entrar en los if marcados con b (para diferenciarlos, en los demas sí entra.)

En otros lugares de la app tengo algo parecido y sí entran, pero en estos no: aunque pasa por todos ellos hace la comparación, ve que son iguales pero no entra.

El trozo de código funciona como yo quiero excepto en esos if que no le da la gana de entrar y no sé por qué hace eso, ya que se ejecuta después del map.

```
mfirestoreTurnos.collection("Turnos")
        .get().addOnCompleteListener(
            new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot qDSTurnos : task.getResult()) {
            String idturno = qDSTurnos.getString("idturno");
           // String nombreturno = qDSTurnos.getString("nombreturno");
            mfirestoreTurnos.collection("Aulas")
                .whereEqualTo("idturno", idturno)
                .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                            // ...
                            
                            String libre = "ghXAL4xpzTpahxA5pzcO";
                            String interna = "igxT7sIFCk3xXu7i7oHL";
                            String discapacidad = "W4Ck7H6E32jlne761nIj";
                            DecimalFormat form = new DecimalFormat("###,##0");
                            DecimalFormat formporciento = new DecimalFormat("##0,00 %");;
    
                         b   if ( idturno == libre ) {
                                // ...
                             }
    
                          b  if ( idturno == interna ) {
                                // ...
                            }
    
                         b   if ( idturno == discapacidad ) {
                                // ...
    
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Debes usar `equals()` para comparar cadenas. Así, si `libre` es una cadena, debes hacer: `if ( idturno.equals(libre) )`.

Comment: He simplificado un poco el código, omitiendo lo que no es necesario para que se vea claramente el problema

Answer (score 2):

En el código se puede ver que `idturno` es de tipo `String` y que `libre`, `interna` y `discapacidad` también son de tipo `String`. Por tanto, **debes usar **[`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object))** para comparar dos objetos de tipo `String`**.

De modo que tus `if`  deben quedar así:

```
if ( idturno.equals(libre) ) {
    // ...
}


if ( idturno.equals(interna) ) {
    // ...
}


if ( idturno.equals(discapacidad) ) {
    // ...
}
```

Si `idturno` fuese de tipo `int` o `Integer`, entonces debes convertir `libre` a ese tipo para hacer la comparación y ahí sí usarías el comparador `==`:

```
if ( idturno == Integer.parseInt(libre) ) {
    // ...
```

En este segundo caso, deberás agregar un control, para que el código no se rompa en caso de valores no convertibles a número.

Si es algo que vas a usar mucho, puedes crear tu propio método:

```
/*
    Intenta convertir una cadena a entero
    Si no es posible, devuelve 0
    El valor devuelto puede ser otro,
    por ejemplo -1, dependiendo de la naturaleza
    de tu aplicación
*/
public Integer toInteger(String string) {
    try {
            return Integer.parseInt(string);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Y para usarlo:

```
if ( idturno == toInteger(libre) ) {
    // ...
```